# R ggplot2 draw a label box around ggtext for geom_hline

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the data and code below, how can I add a label boundary box (similar to when you hover your mouse over a line and the value shows up with a boundary box via `ggplotly`) as shown in the desired output below?

As a note for some unknown reason the mean horizontal line appears `black`, even though in the legend it's `blue` (as defined in the code).

Desired Output:

[image]

Sample data (`AvgTMeanYear`):

```
structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(24.2700686838937, 
23.8852956598276, 25.094446596092, 24.1561175050287, 24.157183605977, 
24.3047482638362, 24.7899738481466, 24.5756232655603, 24.5833086228592, 
24.7344695534483, 25.3094451071121, 25.2100615173707, 24.3651692293534, 
24.5423890611494, 25.2492166633908, 24.7005097837931, 24.2491591827443, 
25.0912281781322, 25.0779264303305, 24.403294248319, 24.4983991453592, 
24.4292324356466, 24.8179824927011, 24.7243948463075, 24.5086534543966, 
24.2818632071983, 24.4567195220259, 24.8402224356034, 24.6574465515086, 
24.5440715673563, 23.482670620977, 24.9979594684914, 24.5452453980747, 
24.9271462811494, 24.7443215819253, 25.8929839790805, 25.1801908261063, 
25.2079308058908, 25.0722425561207, 25.4554644289799, 25.4548979078736, 
25.0756772250287)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

Code:

```
    AvgTMeanYear %>%
     group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(tmean = mean(AvgTMean,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= year, y=tmean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Historic Trend"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(AvgTMeanYear$tmean), aes(color="Average Temperature")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Average Temperature" = "blue","Historic Trend" = "black"), name = "Legend") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Avg. Mean T. (\u00B0C)") +
  ggtitle("Temperature Trend 1980-2021") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1980 , y = 24.6, label = "24.47 \u00B0C"))
```

Comment: `geom_label` works exactly like `geom_text` except that it puts the text within a ... label/bounding-box. It won't "point" to the data point, though, for that you may want to look at the [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/index.html) package.

Comment: FYI, `'tmean' not found`

Comment: @r2evans fixed it, it should work now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: _Run your code_. `object 'AvgTMean' not found`. You missed changing one reference to `tmean`.

Comment: Sorry about that it should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's approach all issues.

1. `geom_label` draws a box around the text.
2. We can fix the blue line problem by forcing different data for `geom_hline`. Tbh, I'm not entirely certain why your initial literal approach did not work, but this one does.
3. Because of where the labels is located, we can turn off clipping to make sure it is all visible. (This may not always be an issue.) (This could also be resolved by using `hjust=` and `yjust=` for manual control, or the `ggrepel` package for dynamic/stochastic "forcing" things away from data.)

```r
AvgTMeanYear %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(AvgTMean = mean(AvgTMean ,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= year, y=AvgTMean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Historic Trend"), stat = "identity") +
  # UPDATED to add new data and put yint inside aes
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = y, color = "Average Temperature"),
             data = data.frame(col="Average Temperature", y=24.4)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Average Temperature" = "blue","Historic Trend" = "black"), name = "Legend") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Avg. Mean T. (\u00B0C)") +
  ggtitle("Temperature Trend 1980-2021") +
  # UPDATED to change geom_text to geom_label
  geom_label(aes(x = 1980 , y = 24.6, label = "24.47 \u00B0C")) +
  # ADDED
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image: ggplot with boxed text and blue line]

Comment: Cheers for that, is there a way to make the box transparent, so that it does not cover the black trend line.

Comment: Yes, use `geom_label(aes(x = 1980 , y = 24.6, label = "24.47 \u00B0C"), fill = "transparent")`

Comment: Bingo works like a charm :) and thank you for referring `ggrepel`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `geom_label()`? For example,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(x = 2.62, y = 21, label = "Mazda RX4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Option using `annotate` and with separate dataframe for `geom_hline`:

```r
AvgTMeanYear <- structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(24.2700686838937, 
                                                              23.8852956598276, 25.094446596092, 24.1561175050287, 24.157183605977, 
                                                              24.3047482638362, 24.7899738481466, 24.5756232655603, 24.5833086228592, 
                                                              24.7344695534483, 25.3094451071121, 25.2100615173707, 24.3651692293534, 
                                                              24.5423890611494, 25.2492166633908, 24.7005097837931, 24.2491591827443, 
                                                              25.0912281781322, 25.0779264303305, 24.403294248319, 24.4983991453592, 
                                                              24.4292324356466, 24.8179824927011, 24.7243948463075, 24.5086534543966, 
                                                              24.2818632071983, 24.4567195220259, 24.8402224356034, 24.6574465515086, 
                                                              24.5440715673563, 23.482670620977, 24.9979594684914, 24.5452453980747, 
                                                              24.9271462811494, 24.7443215819253, 25.8929839790805, 25.1801908261063, 
                                                              25.2079308058908, 25.0722425561207, 25.4554644289799, 25.4548979078736, 
                                                              25.0756772250287)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          -42L))                                                              
df_hline <- data.frame(col_line = "Average Temperature", y = mean(AvgTMeanYear$AvgTMean))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
AvgTMeanYear %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(tmean = mean(AvgTMean ,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= year, y=tmean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Historic Trend"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(df_hline, mapping = aes(yintercept = y, color="Average Temperature")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Average Temperature" = "blue","Historic Trend" = "black"), name = "Legend") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Avg. Mean T. (\u00B0C)") +
  ggtitle("Temperature Trend 1980-2021") +
  annotate("label", x = 1985 , y = 25, label = "24.47 \u00B0C")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Cheers for another method, this is also works :)